# Prescribing the discriminant locus of fiber spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, minimal-model-program

Let $X$ be a projective manifold with $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} X \geq 3$. Assume $X$ is the total space of a fiber space, i.e., there is a proper surjective holomorphic map $f : X \to Y$ with connected fibers. The discriminant locus of $f$ is the set of all points $y \in Y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is singular. We will assume $Y$ is a normal irreducible projective variety with $0 < \dim_{\mathbb{C}} Y < \dim_{\mathbb{C}} X$.

---

The following general question interests me:

Given a divisor $D \subset Y$, can we construct a fiber space $f : X \to Y$ whose discriminant locus is $D$?

---

This question is too big, so I will ask a more specific question:

Can we construct an example of a fiber space $f : X \to Y$ where the codimension-one part of the discriminant locus does not have normal crossings?

---

Notice that if we look at surfaces $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} X =2$, then the discriminant locus is a finite set of discrete points on a curve.

---

**Edit:** I would like to add that I would appreciate as many examples/references as one has. I think it is worth cultivating a bank of examples.

Comment: Just take any fiber bundle over $Y$ of fiber dimension $\geq 1$, then take a section over $D$, then form the blowing up of the total space along the image of $D$ under the section, and finally resolve any singularities of the new total space.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just give an example. Let $V$ be a vector space, set $Y = \mathbb{P}(S^2V^\vee)$, and let
$$
X \subset \mathbb{P}(V) \times \mathbb{P}(S^2V^\vee)
$$
be the *universal quadric*, i.e., the natural divisor of bidegree $(2,1)$. The projection $X \to  \mathbb{P}(V)$ is a projectivization of a vector bundle, hence $X$ is smooth. On the other hand, the projection
$$
X \to Y = \mathbb{P}(S^2V^\vee)
$$
is a quadric bundle, its discriminant divisor $D \subset \mathbb{P}(S^2V^\vee)$ is the symmetric determinantal hypersurface, and it is not a normal crossing divisor (it is normal, but singular) when $\dim(V) \ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I'm not familiar with the construction, do you have any references? Or perhaps, even a heuristic for constructing such examples?

Comment: Essentially, there is no reason for the discriminant divisor to be normal crossing. So, if you take a general morphism $f$ it will give you an example similar to the above.